# How to override wordpress posts in the template

Tags: php, wordpress, overriding

I am designing a template for Wordpress. By default, Wordpress prints the posts in the following manner,

```
<div class="vevent_list rMarginLg">
<div id="L20150808ld" class="entry">
  <h3 class=""><a rel="bookmark" href="link">Hello world!</a></h3>
  <p class="date"><span title="2015-08-08T02:09:51+0000" class="dtstart published">08 August 2015</span> | <a href="link/#comments">Comments (1)</a></p>
  <p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>
    <!--p class="meta">  &#8212;   
       </p -->
    <div class="feedback">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

but I want it to be printed in the following way,

```
<div class="c1">
      <div class="c2">
         <h3 class="c3">
            <span class="c4"><a href="link">Hello world!</a></span>
         </h3>
         <p class="c5">
            <span title="2015-08-08T02:09:51+0000" class="dtstart published"> 08 August 2015 </span>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="c6"><p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!</p>
</div>
```

I want to do this in the right way, not manipulating wordpress core functions. How can I do that? Is there a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit single.php in your theme.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="c1">
      <div class="c2">
         <h3 class="c3">
            <span class="c4"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></span>
         </h3>
         <p class="c5">
            <span title="<?php the_date();?>" class="dtstart published"><?php the_date();?></span>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="c6"><?php the_content();?></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where should I include `single.php`?

Comment: in your theme folder (wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME)

Comment: The question is where should I include it? If I just put it in that folder, it won't recognize its code. How can I call it in my `index.php` or other main template files?

Comment: create single.php and put in that folder. WordPress alone will understand that is the template for a single post